# calling a C# custom action from InstallShield getting error can't find InstallShield.Interop.Msi

Tags: c#, custom-action, installshield-2016

I've an extremely simple installer set up that tries to call a custom action (Call a public method in a managed assembly) and yet when I call it I get the error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'InstallShield.Interop.Msi.

This file is in the same folder as the .dll, so how do I get it included in my project so that it can resolve during execution. I've called methods before this way and never gotten this error, so I really don't understand why I'm getting it now.

Comment: You need to list it in the ISClrWrap table; your prior projects probably have this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752969/installshield-customaction-how-to-load-the-managed-dependency-assemblies

Comment: Thanks, but this problem just disappeared. No explanation - it just started working.